# Angular 2 material mat-tab size

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have the following piece of code

```
  <mat-tab-group>
    <div *ngFor="let question of subcategory.questions">
        <mat-tab label={{question.question_id}} class="question-tab">{{question.question}}</mat-tab>
    </div>
  </mat-tab-group>
```

which displays like: 
[image]

However I want to reduce tabs width, like this:
[image]

The problem is, when I change css at run time, it adjusts fine, but when I put css like:

```
.mat-tab {
  min-width: 50px !important;
}
.mat-tab-label[_ngcontent-c9]{
    min-width: 50px !important;
}
```

It doesn't work. Any idea how to approach this ?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try this:

```
/deep/.mat-tab-label, /deep/.mat-tab-label-active{
 min-width: 0!important;
 padding: 3px!important;
 margin: 3px!important;
}
```

**NOTE:** In angular 8 `/deep/` not working... you can use `::ng-deep`, like so:

```
::ng-deep.mat-tab-label, ::ng-deep.mat-tab-label-active{
 min-width: 0!important;
 padding: 3px!important;
 margin: 3px!important;
}
```

Comment: well first one i tried already, found at https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1092
and second one too i tried thats why i have question-tab. The thing is it still doesnt work

Comment: @AishwatSingh '/deep/' only worked with .SCSS file not css.

Comment: @AishwatSingh i have tested. and update answer please try it.

Comment: doesn't seem to work with nav tabs.  Any clues for how to set the width of those?

Comment: if you add this solution all the tabs in the app will get updated(independently that you add it on a single component), if you don't want that,add an id on the tab-group and used on the scss/css

Comment: you should use ::ng-deep not /deep/ anymore.

Comment: any solution without ng-deep @JanneHarju

Comment: Yes @Yasar Arafath , you can use `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation

Comment: Prefix with with :host selector in order to not apply this to other tabs in your project, so :host /deep/.mat-tab-label, :host /deep/.mat-tab-label-active { ...

Comment: As said by @Juan for setting width only for specific mat tab group using id #group {
    ::ng-deep.mat-tab-label, ::ng-deep.mat-tab-label-active{
        min-width: 0!important;
        padding: 3px !important;
        margin: 3px !important;
    }
}

Comment: Working without important

Answer (score 6):

In my case the accepted answer didn't work well - when switching between tabs the width of `body` of specific tab was changing and it didn't look nice, so I added mat-tab-link to resolve it

```
::ng-deep.mat-tab-link,  ::ng-deep.mat-tab-label, ::ng-deep.mat-tab-label-active{
    min-width: 97px!important;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Without `!important`:

```css
/* 
    ::ng-deep disables view-encapsulation of Angular components 
        -> to avoid global style bleeding use it in combination with :host
        -> https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep
*/
:host ::ng-deep .mat-tab-label {
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: It looks perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

If you want to control the `height` and `width` of `angular material` tabs use styles followed by `::ng-deep`. Check the below code to modify `height` and `width`

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-label
{
  height: 27px !important;
  min-height: 5px!important;
  margin: 3px!important;
  width: 90px!important;
  min-width: 5px!important;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
.mat-tab-group > .mat-tab-header > .mat-tab-label-container > .mat-tab-list > .mat-tab
labels {
  .mat-tab-label[role^='tab'] {
    min-width: 72px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

adding disablePagination worked for me:

```html
<mat-tab-group disablePagination>
    <div *ngFor="let question of subcategory.questions">
        <mat-tab label={{question.question_id}} class="question-tab">{{question.question}}</mat-tab>
    </div>
</mat-tab-group>
```