# Angular 5.2 material component how to remove extra spaces

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have built my first angular application but so far no luck to have better control on the space used by some material components.

1. `mat-tab-label`, which is too wide, I followed this: [Angular 2 material md-tab size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386840/angular-2-material-md-tab-size)
   and have the css:

   ```css
   ::ng-deep .mat-tab-label, ng-deep .mat-tab-label-active{
       min-width: 60px!important;
       padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px !important;
       margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px !important;
       font-size:12px;
   }
   ```

I am able to have better width control, but it is still a bit too tall. Is it possible to change the height of the tab-label?

2. The mat-form-field, with an input field and auto-complete. So far not able to change the overall height of the field.

   ```html
   <div class="mysymbolform">
       <mat-form-field class="symbolbox">
       <input class="inputbox" matInput placeholder="enter" 
             value="Enter" [(ngModel)]="value"
             #box autofocus (keyup.enter)="onEnter(box.value)" 
             [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="formCtrl">
             <mat-autocomplete  #auto="matAutocomplete">
               <mat-option *ngFor="let result of filteredResult | async"
                     [value]="result.title" >

               </mat-option>


           </mat-autocomplete>
       </mat-form-field>
    </div>
   ```

which height is at least double a normal HTML input field.

3. The `mat-accordion`, `mat-expansion-panel-header`, when it is in expansion mode, too tall also:

   ```css
   ::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel-header  {
        padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
        height:32px !important;
   }
   ```

Thanks a lot!  (And please tell me if there are better ways to compress the spaces of all material components.)